# How to disable keepalive in NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios8, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, keep-alive, persistent-connection

Is there any way to force *NSURLConnection* to not reuse the *current persistent connection* but to create a new one ?

I am trying to defend myself from this known [iOS8 keep-alive bug](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2314)

> If iOS 8 receives a HTTP response with a Keep-Alive header, it keeps this
>   connection to re-use later (as it should), but it keeps it for more
>   than the timeout parameter of the Keep-Alive header and then when a
>   second request comes it tries to re-use a connection that has been
>   dropped by the server.

I am looking for a way to solve this issue from Objective c rather than solving from server side.

If any third party libraries provides a way to ignore Keep-alive header then its also welcome.

This issue is somewhat related to following issues([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28904723/730807),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25372318/730807))

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found is to use `CFNetwork`. Higher level API such as `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession`'s `Connection` header will be overwritten by system.

Comment: So we don't have any option to disable it as of now.

Comment: no way to set value such as close for Connection in HTTP header with NSURLSession, iOS just ignores the value and always sends keep-alive

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can, with low level API such as `CFNetwork`.

Comment: will apple reject the app if we use that low level API ? Can you share the working code snippet ?

Comment: Of course will not be rejected. It is public API. The code is not a snippet but really quite simply, just setting Connect header. You should read the doc.